# Show that Laplacian is zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $u: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be harmonic, i.e. $\Delta u =0.$ Now, I want to show that $\Delta (u(Ox+b))=0$ for an orthogonal matrix $O$ and a constant vector $b$.

Does anybody know how this can be shown?

Regarding the answer, I received.

mhmm. $D(u(Ox+b)) = Du (Ox+b)D(Ox+b)= Du(Ox+b)O.$ I don't quite see how the divergence of this could look like?

Comment: Hint: You can just write $Ox+b$ out as a vector, then find the derivatives.

Comment: Use the fact that $\mathrm{div}(f)(x) = \mathrm{Trace}(Df(x))$, to deduce the 'chain rule' for divergence : $\mathrm{div}(A^{-1} \circ f \circ A)(x) = \mathrm{div}(f)(Ax)$ for $A$ linear invertible (Note : the formula is quite tricky because $f$ is a vector field, so if you change coordinates, then you also have to change coordinates on the vector bundle).

Comment: @user10676 thank you, this is really the best way to do it, I think and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use indexed notation to write the $i$'th component of $Ox+b$ as $\sum_j\,O_{ij}x_j+b_i$.

Then, observe that from the chain rule we have

$$\frac{\partial \,u(Ox+b)}{\partial x_k}=\sum_i\,u_iO_{ik}$$

where the notation $u_i$ designates a partial derivative on the $i$'th argument of $u$.  Now, a second differentiation yields

$$\frac{\partial^2 \,u(Ox+b)}{\partial x_k^2}=\sum_j\sum_i\,u_{ij}O_{jk}O_{ik}$$

Now, we sum over $k$ to find

$$\begin{align}
\sum_k\,\frac{\partial^2 \,u(Ox+b)}{\partial x_k^2}&=\sum_k\sum_j\sum_i\,u_{ij}O_{jk}O_{ik}\\\\
&=\sum_j\sum_i\,u_{ij}\,\sum_k\,O_{jk}O_{ik}\tag 1\\\\
&=\sum_j\sum_i\,u_{ij}\,\delta_{ij} \tag 2 \\\\
&=\sum_i\,u_{ii}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Note in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we made use of the fact that $O$ is orthogonal.  In $(2)$, $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta, which is $1$ if $i=j$ and is zero otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\Delta u(x) = \nabla \cdot \nabla u(x)$. Use chain rule and deduce the claim.

Comment: mhmm. $D(u(Ox+b)) = Du (Ox+b)D(Ox+b)= Du(Ox+b)O.$ I don't quite see how the divergence of this could look like?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions

Comment: I just added the wiki entry for your reference. It hopefully should clear things up. If you still have trouble, try writing it out for $\mathbb{R}^2$, you'll see whats happening.

Comment: are you saying that my chain rule is wrong?

Comment: The notation you used was bad, the end result is correct. I thought you may have been guessing. Try writing out what you have written in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then take the divergence.

Comment: Actually, I have problems dealing with the orthogonal matrix. Could you explain this next divergence step?

Comment: Basically you'll come to a step where you have  $O^T O=1$, since $a \cdot b = a^T b$... try the case with $\mathbb{R}^2$ to see how this comes about, then generalize!

Answer (score 0):

Both [divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) and [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) can be defined in coordinate-free ways, which makes it manifest that they, and therefore their composition the Laplacian, are invariant under translations and orthogonal transformations.